# language switching without changing the current page

Tags: symfony

I use twig for templating in a multilingual Symfony2 project. There is a language switcher in layout.html.twig

I want the user can switch languages without changing the current page by clicking the language link. I have written the following code which just does duty for static pages. Since the language links just pass `locale` to the route, in case of involvement of additional required parameters, it obviously throws the exception: `route has some missing mandatory parameters`

```
<ul id="lang">
    <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {_locale: 'az'}) }}">AZ</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {_locale: 'en'}) }}">EN</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can get the route parameters with `.get('_route_params')` and [merge](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) them with your desired locale:

```
<ul class="lang-menu">
  <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'ca'})) }}">Català</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{  path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'}))}}">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know we aren't supposed to say this at first sight but... I love you !

Comment: Thanks a lot, that made my day

Comment: This should be carved into stone and also to Symfony Docs, haven't found better solution even for Symfony 4.3.