# Symfony 2 link to current page

Tags: php, symfony, twig, routes

How can i create a link to the current in my template?

I want to create a language switcher which should link to the current page in varios languages, so all parameters should be the same exept for the locale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I end up rolling my own function for this. I though at first it was included somewhere in `FrameworkBundle` but did not find anything about it. Here the steps I took.

At first, I created a Twig extension function that would output the same route as the one the user is visiting currently (parameters and query string included). I left this step to you. You can look at [this link](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/customising-the-view-more-with-twig.html#twig-extensions) from a good tutorial on Symfony2 for the description of how to create a Twig extension if you don't know how already. I could help you with it if you need it.

Next step is to create the function itself that will switch the locale of the current route. This function will need the `Request` and `Router` objects as dependencies. In my personal case, I put this function in a dedicated service named `RoutingHelper` service. This service is then used by my Twig extension function. Here the service definition I added to the dependency container:

```
acme.helper.routing:
    class: Application\AcmeBundle\Helper\RoutingHelper
    scope: "request"
    arguments:
        request: "@request"
        router: "@router"
```

And the constructor of my service:

```
protected $request;
protected $router;

public function __construct($request, $router)
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->router = $router;
}
```

The $locale parameter is new locale would like to switch to. Here the function:

```
public function localizeCurrentRoute($locale)
{
    $attributes = $this->request->attributes->all();
    $query = $this->request->query->all();
    $route = $attributes['_route'];

    # This will add query parameters to attributes and filter out attributes starting with _
    $attributes = array_merge($query, $this->filterPrivateKeys($attributes));

    $attributes['_locale'] = $locale;

    return $this->router->generate($route, $attributes);
}
```

Essentially, it does what others have put so far but it also handles parameters and query string. The method `filterPrivateKeys` will remove private attribute from the route attributes. Those attributes are the one starting with an underscore and should not be passed back to the route generator. Here its defintion:

```
private function filterPrivateKeys($attributes)
{
    $filteredAttributes = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($key) && $key[0] != '_') {
            $filteredAttributes[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $filteredAttributes;
}
```

In the end, I'm able to this in my Twig view to create links to switch locales:

```
{% block language_bar %}
        <a href="{{ localize_route('en') }}"> English </a>
        <a href="{{ localize_route('fr') }}"> Français </a>
{% endblock %}
```

**Edit**:

Here my twig extension service definition:

```
acme.twig.extension:
    class: Application\AcmeBundle\Twig\Extension\AcmeExtension
    arguments:
      container: "@service_container"
    tags:
      -  { name: twig.extension }
```

And in the twig extension function I have this call: `$routingHelper = $this->container->get('acme.helper.routing');`

This should solve the scope widening exception happening because the twig extension is not in the request scope.

**Update:**

It is now possible with Symfony 2.1 to have a locale switcher in an easier way than before. Indeed, the 2.1 version of Symfony introduced a new parameter for routes that make it *more* easy to do a locale switcher. Here the code, all in twig

```
{% set route_params = app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') %}

{# merge the query string params if you want to keep them when switching the locale #}
{% set route_params = route_params|merge(app.request.query.all) %}

{# merge the additional params you want to change #}
{% set route_params = route_params|merge({'_locale': 'fr'}) %}

{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), route_params) }}
```

It is still a few lines of twig code, but could be included in a Twig block for easier reuse. Credits to stof, from the Symfony community, for the code above.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Ok, so i have to write it myself. I thought there must be something like that in tne framework, since it is a essentiel function. I managed to write the plugin and the helper class but i have now a problem with the scope. Since the helper and twig extension are in: "scope: "request"" and twig itself isn't (Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "twig" references the service "s2_tools.twig.routing_helper" which belongs to a narrower scope. ). How did you managed this?

Comment: Yeah, I tought this also, but didn't find anything yet. I would love to see something built-in. I did manage this problem by injecting the full service container than retrieving my helper within it. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, i now injected the full service container. It now works. Thanks.

Comment: @Parhs if you have an easier solution, I would like to hear about it When I did this, I thought myself it was a lot of work for that. Maybe this solution could be integrated into a RouterBundle of something like that for easier reuse ...

Comment: @Parhs Added an update to my answer with a *less* work technique to achieve the same thing in Symfony 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) }}">Current page</a>
```

Similar question: [language switching without changing the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677396/language-switching-without-changing-the-current-page)

Comment: Yes, but i want also use the current parameters and only change the locale.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), {'_locale': 'en'}) }}">English</a>
```

Comment: Yes, thats what i already found, i also need the current parameter to build a route for pages with parameters.