# Symfony2 refreshing the same page with a different locale

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

So in the top navigation bar a user can select a language. It works. This is the code:
routing.yml

```
homepage:
  path: /{_locale}
  defaults: { _controller: MpShopBundle:Homepage:index, "_locale": "es"}
  requirements:
         _locale: es|en
```

twig:

```
<li><a href="{{ path('homepage', {'_locale':'en'}) }}">EN</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ path('homepage', {'_locale':'es'}) }}">ES</a></li>
```

Now for the problem. Lets say a user added some products to the cart and accessed the shopping cart page `www.domain.com/cart/shopping-cart`. If he presses one of the links he is redirected to the main index page and his language is changed.

How can I change my code, so that when a user selects a language he is not redirected to a new page, but the same page refreshes with the new locale.

For example:

Current page : `www.domain.com/cart/shopping-cart`

after language select: `www.domain.com/cart/shopping-cart/en`

and not: `www.domain.com/en`

The navbar is being extended by all of my pages. So I need to somehow get the current url and add the /en to it.

I get the url like this:

```
{% set currentPath = path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
                     app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) %}
```

But how can I add the /en part in twig?

Comment: have you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086755/symfony2-use-default-locale-in-routing-one-url-for-one-language ?

Comment: That is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I think this code block answers your question:

`<a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">English</a>`

Taken from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677396/language-switching-without-changing-the-current-page).